# Show UIDatePicker without tapping UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uidatepicker

`UITextField` has an input view. So I can configure input view by making it `UIDatePicker` view. However it's ok if I tap `UITextField` to open date picker. Instead I want to tap UITableView to show date picker which is connected to `UITextField`. Is this possible to do?

Comment: textField.becomeFirstResponder()

Comment: @ShadowOf, crazy I forget about it! thanks a lot!)